# How to get the content of a directory inside of WAR that is inside of an EAR that is inside of a ZIP?

Tags: maven, zip, war, ear, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following :

- **WAR1** that has **/images** directory that contains : photo1.png, photo2.png
- **WAR2** that has **/images** directory that contains : photo2.png, photo3.png
- **WAR3** that has **/images** directory that contains : photo4.png, photo5.png
- **EAR1** that has **WAR1** and **WAR2**
- **EAR2** that has **WAR3**
- **ZIP** file that created by the Maven Assembly plugin that contains **EAR1** and **EAR2**.

Now I need the following :

- While creating the ZIP file by the Maven Assembly plugin, I need to create the directory **/images** inside of the ZIP file that contains the content of **/images** directory of every **WAR** file that is in the **EAR** that is in the **ZIP**.

Please, if not clear let me know guys, so I would give more details.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to [create a separate module](https://github.com/khmarbaise/multiple-artifacts/tree/master/extend) like mod-zip which contains the following pom which has dependencies to all the artifacts and the configuration for maven-assembly-plugin.

You have to change the parent to your parent approriately:

```xml
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.multiple.artifacts</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mod-zip</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Mod: ZIP</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-war1</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-war2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-war3</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-ear1</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>ear</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-ear2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>ear</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>test.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Second you need an assembly descriptor which describes what you like to have which is a little bit tricky:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>test</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <includes>
        <include>${project.groupId}:*:war:${project.version}</include>
      </includes>
      <unpackOptions>
        <includes>
          <include>images/**</include>
        </includes>
      </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>${project.groupId}:*:ear:${project.version}</include>
      </includes>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>result</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

The tricky things is to go via two steps. First filter the artifacts having only the `war`s with the dependencySets and the `unpackOptions` which will filter out the images from them. And second you need to use the EAR modules by using the moduleSets.